# jQTouch and Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, jqtouch

Anyone using Zend Framework to power their jQTouch iPhone Web app?  Looks like jQTouch prefers to have all the "pages" on in one html output.

Anyway, I was just curious if anyone was doing that and was willing to share the skeleton of their project.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not a lot of possibilities here. If you want to have all your output in one view you should perhaps try to use action helpers, all action helper could generate a page and send its output to the response. Take a look at matthew weierophinney's article: http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets.html

Another possibility would be to take a look at jquery mobile instead of jqTouch.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I've never used jquery mobile.  Do you prefer it over jqTouch?

Comment: yes i do, the first mobile javascript library i worked with was jqtouch, the problem with it, is that it is only for iphone. jquery mobile is still alpha but already pretty stable i already did some cool things with it and it's for android, iphone and so on.

Comment: oh and there is also sencha (www.sencha.com) i think they have released a stable version, but i never tried sencha i dunno if its good. on the zend framework side you might find some interesting stuff if you google for WURFL & zf http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=zend+framework+wurfl or the zf docu http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.user-agent-features-wurfl.html

Comment: Thanks, I looked at jquery mobile.  Looks very promising, however it's not quite as smooth on the transitions as jqTouch is...Can't wait to see how it grows out of alpha stage though. :-)  I went ahead and went with jqTouch for now, but will keep a close eye on jquery mobile.